# Unable to get partial view to change dynamically in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Somewhat new to web apps here, and struggling to get this to work. Would appreciate any input.
Essentially, I have a main (Create) view with a dropdown and a partial view. Based on the selected value, the partial view needs to change, i.e. I want to render different .cshtml's.  I've gone through many other similar sounding questions and tried various combinations without success.

The most promising one I found was this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ansh06031982/passing-data-using-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata-session-vari/ but it still doesn't get me what I need. Nothing changes on my View, i.e the partial view does not render even though the debug shows the right values being passed.

**Model:**

```
public class myModelType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string modelType { get; set; }
    public string Input1
    public string Input2
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class myModelTypeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        myModelType myModel = new myModelType();

        return View(myModel);
    }
}

public ActionResult myModelTypeChange(FormCollection form)
{
    String typeSelected = form[“modelTypeDDL”];
    TempData[“modelTypeSelected”] = typeSelected;
    Return RedirectToAction(“myPartialView”);
}

public ActionResult myPartialView()
{
    myModelType myModel = new myModelType();
    string typeSelected = TempData[“modelTypeSelected”];
    string partialViewForm = “”;

    If (typeSelected == “type 1”)
        partialViewForm = “form1”;
    else
        partialViewForm = “form 2”

    return PartialView(partialViewForm, myModel);
}
```

**Main (Create) View**

```
@model myModelType

<script src = “@Url.Content(“~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js”)”></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //bunch of html controls
    @Html.DropDownList(“Model Type”, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>,”- - - “, new { @class = “form-control”, id = “modelTypeDDL})

    //Need to load partial view here
    <div class = “container” id= “partialViewPlaceHolder”>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Rended(“~/bundles/jqueryval”)
}
```

**Partial view 1 (form1.cshtml)**

```
@model myModelType

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    //html specific to form1

    @Html.EditorFor(“model=>model.Input1”, new { @class = “form-control”})
}
```

**Partial view 2 (form2.chstml)**

```
@model myModelType

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    //html specific to form2

    @Html.EditorFor(“model=>model.Input2”, new { @class = “form-control”})
}
```

**jquery script**

```
<script language =”JavaScript” type=”text/javascript”>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(“#modelType”).change(function() {
        $.post(“/myModelTypeController/myModelTypeChange”, {modelType: $(this).val(), function(data){
    $(“partialViewPlaceHolder”).load(data);
      });       
    });
});
</script>
```

The partial view files form1 and form2 are in the same folder as the main Create view.

Would appreciate any help in getting this to work, or any other suggestions on how to get a partial view to switch files based on DDL input.  Thanks!

Comment: I think in this case I would load all partial views and make visible/hidden in the main view depending on your conditions. I also think your RedirectToAction() is wrong. You probably get a page load over and over again, don't you?

Comment: Correction:  The failure mode is not that the partial view doesn't render at all.  Rather, the partial view  doesn't see the "model" and therefore returns a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: @PaulSinnema: hi.  No, I don't see page reloads, unless it's happening so fast (I'm running localhost at this point) that I don't notice it?

Comment: Anyway I think the RedirectToAction() should not be used to load partial views.

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:~:text=A%20partial%20view%20is%20a,markup%20files%20are%20called%20pages.

Comment: Thanks.  I've gone ahead and done a "brute force" approach where each of my (7) different partial views is in a different div, and I toggle (in js) which one is shown/hidden based on the DDL selection.  It feels inelegant but it works. Any improvements to this solution would be welcome.